# Ag grid add new empty rows and create record and send it to database after completing filling information

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am new to react. Is there any way to add a new row to **ag-grid** on the button click and fill in the details and after finishing filling in the data send the values database. (by not using the forms) just from the table itself?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You display data in the grid by binding an array of data objects to the grid's "rows" property.

So, on your "button click", just add a new object to the array
(well, actually, you probably need to clone the array, with the new object added).

Then, when the user edits the empty row, they will be editing the new object that was added to the array.